# Map of Collections vs. Map of TreeSets - what is correct syntax?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I'm representing brands with their associated products like so:

- Chipotle

  - 3 mini tacos
  - bowl
  - burrito
- Cookie Shop

  - chocolate chip cookie
  - peanut butter cookie
  - sugar cookie

In code this is represented by a `TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>>`, as the brands will stay sorted alphabetically and enforce no duplicate brands or products. Created by this line:

```
private TreeMap<String, TreeSet<String>> products = loadProducts(RAW_PRODUCTS);
```

I'm still learning Java, but isn't one of the maxims of good OO to use the most-general type wherever you can? So I have this method that takes in this same `Map` and does some processing:

```
void initProductList(final Map<String, Collection<String>> products)
```

And you can see the `TreeMap` has become `Map` and the `TreeSet` has become `Collection`. But whenever I try to call:

```
initProductList(products);
```

The compiler error shows:

```
The method initProductList(Map<String,Collection<String>>) in the type AddAlertItem is not applicable for the arguments (TreeMap<String,TreeSet<String>>)
```

to make it easier to read, this is the difference it's confused on:

```
Map<String,Collection<String>>
TreeMap<String,TreeSet<String>>
```

The difference between `TreeSet` and `Collection` is tripping it up. But I'm not sure what to change to make it work. I *could* downcast the method parameters to specify the `TreeSet` directly, but then I feel I'd be limiting myself as I may want to use another type of `Collection` elsewhere.

Is there something I'm not thinking of, or a way to make this work without giving up the more-generic method parameters?

I've searched a bit on google and here and not found anyone dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collection` is pretty high up the Collections hierarchy.  Why not strengthen the API reference a little bit and go with `Set` instead?

```
void initProductList(final Map<String, ? extends Set<String>> products) {

}
```

This way, it's explicitly clear that you're working with `Set`, and not `List` or some other collection type, as sets behave differently than lists do.

Oh, and it'll also compile.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid @Makoto has got it wrong.

When compiling the codes, jvm will erase the generic type in `<Type>`. So it can't recognize the relationship of *extends* or *implements* between `TreeSet` and `Collection`. As long as the generic types are different, the compiler will show an error. However, `? extends Collection<String>` will work.

Comment: I realized that I had mistyped it; I meant to go with the bounded wildcard instead of the just straight-up `Set` declaration.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for reminding me of that. I've add the bounded wildcard solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass any collection to your method as follows :

```
void initProductList(final Map<String, ? extends Collection<String>> products)
```

Answer (score 2):

Limit it to a `Set` and not a `Collection` and use it as below:

```
 void initProductList(final Map<String, ? extends Set<String>> products){}
```